# Verify which file a request to the server originated from

Tags: authentication, webserver, http, file-upload

In order to make my question clear I will give a practical scenario. Lets say I have a server where I allow people to upload a script and allot them part of my drive, the script can make requests to the server in order to create files, delete them and add data to existing ones.The script lives at a specific path and all the writing and reading needs to be constrained to only that path. The scripts are accessible to anyone and can make requests at any time. However the only problem is that another script can be uploaded to the server and that script can make a request to write on another scripts section of the drive. How can I tell the files apart and make sure that the script making the request to its path lives there?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a security question here. It looks more like an OS or file system feature specific question.

Comment: If you're hand-coding the website, maybe it should be on stack overflow?

Comment: I am hand coding it, but this is more of a theoretical question, I'd like to know what I could do and if it is even possible at all. I think I will have to cross post, and hopefully that doesn't get anyone angry.